# Preview Pane within document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365

I have a simple question that i hope someone can answer.

Is there a way to show a preview pane that will give a "Preview" of whatever file you have highlighted within a document library. Windows has this feature so i was hoping that SharePoint does as well.

I am using Office 365 for Business with SharePoint Online.

Many Thanks, 
Ethan.

Comment: @M.Qassas not duplicate as such because the other questions was about preview at the time of uploading.

Comment: @SharePointer you're right, the question is opened again, and thank u for your great answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can preview a selected document on the document library:

**In the classic document library experience**

[image]

**In the modern experience**
[image]